# Сортировка JSON массива объектов средствами Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Всем доброго времени суток. Я новичок в js, поэтому частенько сталкиваюсь с проблемами при написании скриптов. Короче, у меня есть json массив объектов:

```
var MyJson =
    '[ '+
    '{ "id":"Id","name":"Name","price": "Price","quantity":"Quantity"}, '+
    '{ "id":"123","name":"iPhone XS","price": "1600","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"344","name":"Samsung Galaxy S7","price": "550","quantity":"7"}, '+
    '{ "id":"266","name":"Macbook","price": "900","quantity":"7"},'+
    '{ "id":"478","name":"Asus","price": "400","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"569","name":"Acer","price": "300","quantity":"4"}, '+
    '{ "id":"788","name":"TP-LINK","price": "100","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"124","name":"iPhone SE","price": "350","quantity":"11"}, '+
    '{ "id":"345","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"267","name":"Surface Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}'+
    ']';
```

Возникла необходимость отсортировать объекты скажем по id. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь, как это сварганить средствами Javascript.

Comment: Теперь у вас не объекты а строка =) объекты будут после выполнения вот этой строки: `var Myobj = JSON.parse(MyJson);` опишите функцию для сортировки, и используйте метод sort

Comment: Что-то с функцией сортировки не лады, нашёл на просторах инета function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
} Но что-то не работает. А вызываю в этом моменте: document.getElementById('thId3').addEventListener('click', function () {
        Myobj.sort(dynamicSort('id'));
    });

Comment: Понятия не имею что вы искали, но (я не шибко разбираюсь в JS) я нашел совсем иной пример и судя по коду(по тому как это в прочих ЯП реализуется) - похожее на правду, смотрите ответ через минуту....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var MyJson =
    '[ '+
    '{ "id":"Id","name":"Name","price": "Price","quantity":"Quantity"}, '+
    '{ "id":"123","name":"iPhone XS","price": "1600","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"344","name":"Samsung Galaxy S7","price": "550","quantity":"7"}, '+
    '{ "id":"266","name":"Macbook","price": "900","quantity":"7"},'+
    '{ "id":"478","name":"Asus","price": "400","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"569","name":"Acer","price": "300","quantity":"4"}, '+
    '{ "id":"788","name":"TP-LINK","price": "100","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"124","name":"iPhone SE","price": "350","quantity":"11"}, '+
    '{ "id":"345","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"267","name":"Surface Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}'+
    ']';
    
var data = JSON.parse(MyJson).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});

console.log(data);
```

> А как с name быть? Такая же сортировка уже не работает

```js
var MyJson =
    '[ '+
    '{ "id":"Id","name":"Name","price": "Price","quantity":"Quantity"}, '+
    '{ "id":"123","name":"iPhone XS","price": "1600","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"344","name":"Samsung Galaxy S7","price": "550","quantity":"7"}, '+
    '{ "id":"266","name":"Macbook","price": "900","quantity":"7"},'+
    '{ "id":"478","name":"Asus","price": "400","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"569","name":"Acer","price": "300","quantity":"4"}, '+
    '{ "id":"788","name":"TP-LINK","price": "100","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"124","name":"iPhone SE","price": "350","quantity":"11"}, '+
    '{ "id":"345","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"267","name":"Surface Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}'+
    ']';
 
var data = JSON.parse(MyJson).sort(function(a, b) {
    return ((a.name === b.name) ? 0 : ((a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1));
});
 
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Опередили меня =) да еще и инлайн функция =))

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ахах, скорый поезд :)

Comment: =) JS совсем не мой язык, я его пишу со словарем =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, начинающий?

Comment: в программировании или в JS? в js - не стремлюсь, просто пишу по мере необходимости =) а вообще delphi 10+ лет, пара лет php но для себя чисто, пара лет в си под микроконтроллеры но тоже чисто для себя =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, к чему стремитесь?

Comment: В программировании? это скорее хобби, работа - админ =) А если вопрос немного перефразировать - в последнее время подсел плотно на базы данных =) в частности начал глубже изучать MySQL

Comment: Ребят, а как с name быть? Такая же сортировка уже не пашет. Подскажите

Comment: @ОкуневПаша, добавил в ответ, посмотрите)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, с вами можно связаться во вконтакте?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie say Pie Только контакт? есть вацап, если очень надо скайп\ася\телеграм =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, удобнее всего контакт:), всплакнул с аси(

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ах к черту, давайте телеграмм)

Comment: Если у вас контакт в профиле ваш - написал вам

Answer (score 1):

Что то подобное должно сработать:

```
function compareId(Obj1, Obj2) {
  return Obj1.id - Obj2.id;
}

....
var MyObj = JSON.parse(MyJson);  
MyObj.sort(compareId);
```