# Сортировка JSON массива объектов по строке с помощью Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Всем привет. Я новичок в js, поэтому частенько сталкиваюсь с проблемами при написании скриптов. Короче, у меня есть json массив объектов:

```
var MyJson =
    '[ '+
    '{ "id":"Id","name":"Name","price": "Price","quantity":"Quantity"}, '+
    '{ "id":"123","name":"iPhone XS","price": "1600","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"344","name":"Samsung Galaxy S7","price": "550","quantity":"7"}, '+
    '{ "id":"266","name":"Macbook","price": "900","quantity":"7"},'+
    '{ "id":"478","name":"Asus","price": "400","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"569","name":"Acer","price": "300","quantity":"4"}, '+
    '{ "id":"788","name":"TP-LINK","price": "100","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"124","name":"iPhone SE","price": "350","quantity":"11"}, '+
    '{ "id":"345","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"267","name":"Surface Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}'+
    ']';
```

Возникла необходимость отсортировать объекты по name. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь, как это сварганить средствами Javascript.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка JSON массива объектов средствами Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890236/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-json-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-javascript)

Comment: Ровно так же как в прошлом вопросе, только по полю name а не id

Comment: Хм, логично, только ещё регистр привести к общему

Comment: тогда совсем не ясно зачем вы задали этот вопрос, он совершенно не звучит как "Как приветси к одному регистру 2 строки" или например вот так "как сравнить 2 строки без учета регистра"

Answer (score 2):

```
var MyJson =
    '[ '+
    '{ "id":"Id","name":"Name","price": "Price","quantity":"Quantity"}, '+
    '{ "id":"123","name":"iPhone XS","price": "1600","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"344","name":"Samsung Galaxy S7","price": "550","quantity":"7"}, '+
    '{ "id":"266","name":"Macbook","price": "900","quantity":"7"},'+
    '{ "id":"478","name":"Asus","price": "400","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"569","name":"Acer","price": "300","quantity":"4"}, '+
    '{ "id":"788","name":"TP-LINK","price": "100","quantity":"10"}, '+
    '{ "id":"124","name":"iPhone SE","price": "350","quantity":"11"}, '+
    '{ "id":"345","name":"Samsung Galaxy Note Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}, '+
    '{ "id":"267","name":"Surface Boom","price": "690","quantity":"8"}'+
    ']';

var data = JSON.parse(MyJson).sort(function(a, b) {
    return ('' + a.name).localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(data);
```